# ios AFNetworking Image Downloading Timeouts

Tags: ios, afnetworking

In AFNetworking, I have a bunch of requests for images:

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"image/png", @"image/jpeg", nil];

    for (NSDictionary *anObj in myArray) {
        if ([[aProp objectForKey:@"imageURLs"] count] > 0) {
            [manager GET:[anObj objectForKey:@"imageURLs"][0] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
            {
                // process image
            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                //show ui alert error
            }];
        } 
    }
```

Say I have 10 objects in my array all of which have image URLs to download. If there is a connectivity error, the user gets all 10 error message alert views. Is there a way to cancel the requests still out? Am I doing this correctly in the first place? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you detect a connectivity error you can show one single alert and cancel all pending requests.

```
[manager.operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
```

Comment: where can I call this though? The failure block does not get called on timeout.

Comment: The failure block is definitely called in the case of a timeout